# Living in Sweden & Denmark- building citizenship

Tags: citizenship, sweden, denmark

I'm currently an EU citizen...however that EU citizenship is British thus is greatly under threat. Further I'm an ethnic minority so...let's just say I don't feel safe with the direction the UK is heading. Not to mention the economic downturn.

Luckily I might have a job opportunity in Copenhagen to offer me an escape. The problem with this I see is that Denmark requires 9 years of residence for citizenship. Which is a hell of a long time.

Once upon a time I lived in Sweden. I was there for 2 years. I know that Swedish citizenship requires 5 years of residence. Though I think my previous 2 years do not count this is still a more manageable length of time. I am confident I can get my Swedish up to a fluent level with a year or two study too so that's a worry gone there.

So I'm thinking....maybe if I get this Copenhagen job I can live in Malmo and commute daily? Many do this...

The trouble is...I hate commuting.

So as a possible alternative I'm thinking to keep two residences. Buy myself a proper home on the Swedish side and rent a room to crash in on the Danish side.
The job seems to offer flexiable working and is in the kind of industry where I expect I'll be working like a dog some days and then have some lengthy downtime.

I wonder, how can this dual residence thing work for the purpose of residence?

I am determined above all to do this right and above board- being 100% legally living in Sweden but off the books renting a room and hope nobody notices I'm not home as regularly as a normal person would be isn't something I want to risk.

Could I build years of residence in both? Officially living in two places or must I pick one as my primary?- I assume the latter

How many nights of the year must I ensure I am in my official place in order to make it count?

Comment: FYI, the travel time between Malmö C and Copenhagen C is only about half an hour, so it's not much of a commute. Certainly easier (and cheaper) than having to maintain two residences.

Comment: plus travel time to Malmo C and Copenhagen C.
I'm on a 40 minute commute right now and I hate it. Wish I could bike to work.

Comment: [Apparently](https://www.migrationsverket.se/Privatpersoner/Bli-svensk-medborgare/Medborgarskap-for-vuxna/Tid-i-Sverige.html) you can be outside of Sweden for a maximum of six weeks per year, without consequences. Otherwise they subtract the time spent outside of Sweden, from the five years you need.

Comment: Would it really work if you're apparently working in another country during all this time? I suppose they would want to look at your financial records during your application as well, etc. I know that it seems this citizenship requirement doesn't necessarily require working, as students etc. might still be able to get it if they lived for 5 years, but might still be a bit weird to the authorities. Also wouldn't you be actually paying taxes to the Danish authority all the time? Dunno.

Comment: I have an answer, but considering it was asked 5 years ago, this might be too late.  If not, let me know and I can type it out.